# How to create a recursive function to calculate Fibonacci numbers

Tags: python, recursion

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n ==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

How do I make this recursive? When I run the programme and enter a digit, the same digit is given back

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write the Fibonacci Sequence in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-python)

Comment: How do you invoke this function?

Comment: @aga With either fib(0), fib(1), or fib(5). See Martijn's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21046091/667820)

Comment: @HenkLangeveld I know how to make a call of function, I wanted to know how exactly OP does that - this function is already recursive, so in order to get the issue he gets ("When I run the programme and enter a digit, the same digit is given back") he has to call it in a wrong manner.

Comment: @aga, I was trying to point out that OP's test methods were not exhaustive.  For any value from [0,1,5], he will get the described results.  OP's sample space was too small.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld I feel sooo stupid, many thanks for clarification. :)

Answer (score 6):

Your function is **already** recursive. You simply need to pass in a number other than 0, 1, or 5 to see the effect:

```
>>> def fib(n):
...     if n == 0:
...         return 0
...     elif n ==1:
...         return 1
...     else:
...         return fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
... 
>>> fib(0)  # returns immediately, because n == 0
0
>>> fib(1)  # returns immediately, because n == 1
1
>>> fib(2)  # returns fib(1) + fib(0) == 1 + 0 == 1
1
>>> fib(3)  # returns fib(2) + fib(1) == (fib(1) + fib(0)) + 1 == (1 + 0) + 1 == 2
2
>>> fib(100) # returns fib(99) + fib(98) == (fib(98) + fib(97)) + (fib(97) + fib(96)) == ...
# This one takes a while because 2**100 calculations need to be completed
354224848179261915075
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is an example about what can go wrong with recursion, because it exhibits quadratic complexity for a problem that has a trivial solution with linear complexity.  You normally wouldn't use recursion here.  That said, it is possible to use recursion here an keep linear complexity:

```
def fib(n):
    def aux( n ):
        if( n==1 ):
            return (0, 1)
        else:
            (a,b) = aux( n-1 )
            return b, a+b
    return  aux(n)[1]
```

Comment: OP's code time complexity is not quadratic; it is exponential (that is much much worse).

Answer (score 0):

As an exercise, here's a Fibonacci Sequence Generator
that does not use recursion and therefore won't hit
Python's *recursion limit* for large values of `n`:

```
def fib():
    a, b = 0, 1
    yield a
    yield b
    while True:
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield b
```

**Example:**

```
>>> f = fib()
>>> next(f)
0
>>> next(f)
1
>>> next(f)
1
>>> next(f)
2
>>> next(f)
3
>>> next(f)
5
>>> next(f)
8
>>> next(f)
13
```

*First 10 Fibonacci Numbers:*

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> list(islice(fib(), 0, 10))
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is already recursive, and correct.  You must have used a very small number of tests.  If your testing method produced these results, you can only have used some of the digits 0, 1, and 5.  Try larger integers.